# Batch if exist always returns false

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, exists

Never wrote a batch script before so I'm in the learning process but...

I'm trying to create a script to automatically map network drives. I included an `if exist` statement to determine if the folder exists. But it keeps exiting the `if statement` as if the folder doesn't exist even when it does. When I run the command separately it works (e.g. `if exist \\domain\folder\desired_folder (echo true) else (echo false)` will echo true). Seems like it passes the `if statements` and goes straight to the `else statement`

Here is my code that I'm having issues with, it should be going into the first `if statement` and mapping the drive... Any help would be appreciated.

```
REM define %A and %B
SET totalname="net user %USERNAME% /domain | FIND /i "Full Name""  

FOR /f "tokens=3-4 delims=, " %%A IN ('%totalname%') DO SET drivename=%%A_%%B


REM check if I drive folder exists
if exist "\\domain\folder\%%A_%%B" (
REM delete current I drive
REM map I drive
net use i: /delete
net use i: \\domain\folder\%drivename% /P:YES
) else if exist \\domain\folder\%USERNAME% (
    net use i: /delete
    net use i: \\domain\folder\%USERNAME% /P:YES
) else (
    echo ERROR: File Not Found
    echo ERROR: Unable to map I drive

    REM for debugging purposes: %username% & %drivename% echo the desired result
    echo username %USERNAME%
    echo a_b %drivename%
    pause
    exit
)
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete, you do not show where `%%A` and `%%B` come from. Please provide a [mcve]! Perhaps the problem is related to lack of [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). Also put the paths in between `""` to avoid trouble if they contain spaces or other special charactrers...

Comment: I'm using the following commands to define `%A` and `%B` 

`SET totalname="net user %USERNAME% /domain | FIND /i "Full Name""`
and
`FOR /f "tokens=3-4 delims=, " %%A IN ('%totalname%') DO SET drivename=%%A_%%B`

Comment: @aschipfl thanks, I added where I get `%A` and `%B` and in the path that I'm trying to get there are no spaces or special characters but I will add " " to see if it makes a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%%A` and `%%B` only exist in the context of the `for /F` loop, so `%%A` and `%%B` outside of the loop are going to be expanded to `%A` and `%B` literally. You are assigning `%%A_%%B` in the loop to variable `drivename`, so use `%drivename%` later rather than `%%A_%%B`:

In addition, I recommend the quoted `set` syntax, and to put quotes around all paths.

So:

```cmd
for /F "tokens=3-4 delims=, " %%A in ('
    net user %USERNAME% /domain ^| find /I "Full Name"
') do set "drivename=%%A_%%B"
rem // more code...
if exist "\\domain\folder\%drivename%" (
    rem // more code...
) else if exist "\\domain\folder\%USERNAME%" (
    rem // more code...
) else (
    rem // more code...
)
```